# How to deploy an Windows 8 app with Microsoft Intune

Tags: deployment, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, intune

I'm trying to deploy an application developed for WinRT devices (for tablets and convertible devices 2 in 1, not for Windows Phone devices).

I want that the client devices having an automatic instal·lation (that user doesn't need to do nothing to install the app).

I have opened a demo Intune account, and when I try to publish the app, the options that there are available are: "Required Install", "Uninstall" and "Available".

When in Intune I try to deploy an app, the assistent says: "When the approval action is either Required Install or Uninstall, this app be applicable only to mobile and does not apply to client computers".

It's possible to deploy an WinRT/Metro application without user intervention?

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft is talking about client computers in Intune they actually mean PCs managed by the Intune agent.

On PCs managed through the MDM Channel you should be able to deploy Appx required and the app is pushed down.